# Issue with Devise Email Confirmation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I am a rails newbie. I encountered something strange when I am using Devise for the first time. Could you please let me know if this is a Devise Bug or an issue on my end?

I am using Devise 2.0.1

**After a new user signs up, email is sent to the registered email address.**

**Case 1:**

**This part is Ok**

Once confirmed through the email link, he is able to access the entire site.

**Case 2:**

**This part is not Ok**

After I sign up, I immediately without clicking on the confirm link, I go to sign in page and try to sign in with the just created email account and password, it **does not** show any error, it simply routes to the sign_in page.. Ideally I would like it to show an error something like

```
"We have sent you an email. Please confirm. 
If you have not received them please ask for conformation instructions"
```

**Case 3:**

**This part is not Ok**

After I sign up, I click the forgot password lnk. I enter the email address I just signed up with..it sends me a reset password instructions. Instead of reset password instructions, I would ideally like to send me an error saying `"Email first has to been confirmed first in order to send reset password instructions."`

Looking forward for your help and support.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I need to let people know about confirmations, I usually set this up in one of my controllers:

```
render :template => 'shared/unconfirmed' and return if current_user.confirmed? == false
```

This stops people doing anything unless they have confirmed, and the restriction requirements determine where I put it. For example, if you want to block people doing everything until they have confirmed, put it in a before_filter in your application_controller. If you want them to stop creating Posts, put it in the Posts controller.

For this to work, you'll really should also change the default value of "config.confirm_within" setting in the devise.rb config file to let people in:

```
# ==> Configuration for :confirmable
# A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
# confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
# able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
# access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
# the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
# config.confirm_within = 2.days
```

Comment: I tried doing this.. but I am getting an error! Also, I dont want to give user 2 day access in the first place. I am more looking at the Devise Bug.. Case 3 & Case 2 mentioned above..